# Бессмысленные бекапы при diskcryptor, как победить?

Tags: windows, криптография, резервное-копирование, windows-server-2012

Вся инфраструктура на Windows Server 2012(r2).
Начальник очень много читал сайты о краже серверов и т.д.
Решил зашифровать все сервера программой  [diskcryptor.](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page)
Данная программа шифрует все разделы и после этого при старте сервера нужно вбить этот самый пароль и только после этого загрузится винда.
После этого начал проверять свои бекапы. Но столкнулся с проблемой.
После того, как выворачиваю бекап, происходит такая же ситуация: "черный экран и нужно вбить пароль при шифровании разделов" **НО** этот пароль не подходит.
Пробовал эти диски подсоединять и смотреть через diskcryptor и он видит эти разделы и они не зашифрованы. Пробовал зашифровать и грузануться, но все равно безрезультатно.
Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Буду весьма благодарен. А то как-то не спится без работающих бекапов....

Comment: Я так понимаю, что бэкп делается на уровне разделов и файловой табилцы?

Comment: Acronis забирает все mbr, зарезервировано системой и диск С.

Comment: Это всё делается через сервер\клиент на лету, автоматом и по расписанию?

Comment: Да, это делается на лету по расписанию. Сервер без клиентов. Только Acronis Backup & Recovery 11.5 и все.

Comment: А если потушенный серврер забэкапить и потом развернуть?

Answer (score 0):

> Цитата Пробовал эти диски подсоединять и смотреть через diskcryptor и он видит эти разделы и они не зашифрованы

Он вообще видит все разделы.
Если разделы не зашифрованы, попробуй просто нажать Esc. Возможно, загрузчик dcryptor в PBR. Запрос пароля и зашифрованный раздел -- не обязательно связанные факты.